# Flutter: GetX place multiple pages on the stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I use Getx for route management in my Flutter application.

When a certain notification arrives and the app starts from terminated state I want:

- launch the `/` route (launch screen)
- go to `potm/:match_id` route
- when user presses back go to `match/:match_id` route
- when user presses back go to `home` route

Basically I want to have this stack: `home` -> `match/:match_id` -> `potm:/match_id` and then popping from the top will bring me back at `home`

In the `/` page initState method I do the following

```
var matchId = getMatchId();
Get.offToNamed("/home");                         // place home on stack and remove /
Get.toNamed("/match/" + matchId);                // place /match/:match_id on stack 
await Get.toNamed("/potm/" + matchId);           // go to /potm/:match_id
```

this kind of works but in some devices I see a very fast transition from `/` to `/home` which I don't want to see

What is the best way to achieve my desired stack here?

Comment: any updates on this? I am facing the same issue. Please answer this question if you have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t find a way using imperative navigation.
I opted for declarative navigation using GoRouter